# Error when running two web applications at the same time in tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, web-applications, mariadb, spring-tool-suite

I have a web application (maven) which uses mariadb as a database and I'm deploying the app with Tomcat on a Raspberry Pi.

Since I wanted to create and deploy a similar version of the original application. I slightly modified the application (which has originally been created by another person). The only change that I made to the application was to connect it to another database instance on my Raspberry Pi, by changing this line:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/myDatabase2_db
```

Of course, I created a database by the name of "myDatabase2_db" on the Raspberry Pi in advance. And I also changed the name of the WAR-file to MYAPP2, so that the two applications have different names.

My goal was to deploy the original application and the modified version as completely separate applications (with different databases), but on the same Tomcat instance on my Raspberry Pi.

My observations so far:
(1) If I stop the "original" application in Tomcat and AFTERWARDS deploy the "modified" application and try to run it, it works without any issues.

(2) Only when I try to run both applications at the same time in Tomcat, it always displays the following error in tomcat:

> FAIL - Application at context path /MYAPP2 could not be started FAIL -
> Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
> to start component
> [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MYAPP2]]

So far, my guess is that this happens because I used the same code basis for both applications and only changed the above-mentioned 1 line of code. Do I for example have to change something in the pom.xml file or somewhere else?

The problem is just that I didn't create the original application and only have a very limited unterstanding of maven, mariadb and tomcat. I would really appreciate if someone could explain what is happening and how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add the full stack trace of the error (`Caused by...` included).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Can you tell me where I can find the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: If you didn't disable logging, look in the `logs` folder of Tomcat's installation.